# Amazon EC2 pricing for blocked IP addresses

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

Let say someone is brute forcing my EC2 website and i block that ip address using my EC2 ubuntu firewall and now if that user from that ip would access my website it will show 400 BAD REQUEST.

So my question is that will amazon charge me for this 400 BAD Request as amazon charges you for each request sent out of your instance.

Comment: The incoming traffic is free, according to AWS price page: https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/on-demand/. So if you were not to respond to the blocked IP at all, that should not be charged.

Answer (score 1):

All data coming is actually free, however the point in sending back data out of the network. If you blocked the IP address inside your instance itself in some kind of 400 HTTP response code as you shared in your question, that means the request will go all the way through their network until it reaches to your instance then you block and send back bad response back in this case it is like normal request with special kind of response I believe they will charge you in this case for any  data transfer in/out of their network.

However, If you make such blocks in security groups or network access control list NACL you wouldn't have any charges or fees for such kind of data transfer.

Note: The cost below may vary based on the selected region

[image]

Comment: Thanks for you answer but i have one more question. I want to dynamically block IP address anyone who will send lot of request. So how will do that dyanmically blocking within Security Groups so amazon will not charge me any cost for data transfer out.

Comment: @AmanBansal You could do this using VPC FlowLogs, CloudWatch Events, to trigger Lambda to block IPs in network ACLs. you could also use AWS Shield which is an enhanced DDoS protection service you could use. you could protect your application with Shield at no additional cost If you use one of the following Route53, Load Balancer or CloudFront distribution. Read this https://aws.amazon.com/answers/networking/aws-ddos-attack-mitigation/ - overview of AWS Shield https://aws.amazon.com/shield/